# How can I override a java button to have new actions

Tags: java, awt, actionevent

Sorry if this question was already asked. I couldnt find anything!

I have been working on this game for school (Grade 10).

I am trying to override a button action so each click is worth 2 rather than 1.

```
    private void BuyPowerClickActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        if (money >= 1000) {
            money = money - 1000;
            CoinCounter.setText(money + "");
            CoinCounter1.setText(money + "");

        @Override
        public void run(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
                    CoinCounter.setText(money + "");
                    CoinCounter1.setText(money + "");
                                money = money + (click * 2);        
        }
    }                                             
    }
```

I dont quite understand whats wrong here if possible please help!

EDIT:

Ok so I was messing around with it and came out with this.

```
    private void BuyPowerClickActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        if (money >= 1000) {
            money = money - 1000;
            CoinCounter.setText(money + "");
            CoinCounter1.setText(money + "");

        @Override
        public void run(){
                    CoinCounter.setText(money + "");
                    CoinCounter1.setText(money + "");
                    click = click * 2;      
        }`enter code here`
    }                                             
    }
```

Im only confused on how that doesnt work but this one does for an "auto clicker" type thing.

```
   private void BuyCoinFountainActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        if (money >= 500) {
            CoinFountain++;
            money = money - 500;
            CoinCounter.setText(money + "");
            CoinCounter1.setText(money + "");
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    money = money + CoinFountain - 1;
                    CoinCounter.setText(money + "");
                    CoinCounter1.setText(money + "");

                }

            }, 500, 500);
        }
    }
```

If you could help that would be great

Comment: You're probably going to find this difficult to do, as the code stands, as the method is `private` and can't be overridden. A better solution would be to move the "core" functionality out of the UI code and into a model of some kind, this way you could "replace" the model with a different implementation and the UI could still work (as it's based on the state of the model)

Comment: Alright but I have been messing with this and shouldnt this work though?

Comment: private void BuyPowerClickActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        if (money >= 1000) {
            money = money - 1000;
            CoinCounter.setText(money + "");
            CoinCounter1.setText(money + "");

        @Override
        public void run(){
                    CoinCounter.setText(money + "");
                    CoinCounter1.setText(money + "");
                    click = click * 2;      
        }
    }                                             
    }

Comment: Sorry for spamming I havent used this site before

Comment: You can't define a method within a method and since I have zero context to the original code, this is little else I can add

Comment: Alright man I understand. If it would help you could check out my edit on my post. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [mcve]. Also clarify exactly what are you trying to achieve and what is wrong with code posted.

Comment: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.